# How to link parameters between a main and sub-report

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports for Net 4.0.

My Main report and my sub-report and based on two different stored procedure. They both use the same parameter SubmissionControlId. The value of SubmissionControlId is not passed back to main report only to the sub-report. I want to link the values so that whatever value is passed to SubmissionControlId in the main report is also used when the sub-report stored procedure is called.

I cannot get the syntax correct. I think I need to use shared variables but I’m not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can the parameter **SubmissionControlId** only in Main report and remove the same parameter from Sub-Report.

Now right click the sub report and select **change sub-report links** which shows with a dialog box where you can configure the linking between main report to sub report.

After linking is done, you can see the same parameter in the main report found in your sub report also. And in sub report record select formula you can find records are selected based on the main report's parameter.

Hope this helps. Try and get back with results.

Comment: Thanks for responding. <<remove the same parameter from Sub-Report.<< I cannot remove this pararemeter, it is a parameter passed by the stored procedure. <<change sub-report links<< I can select the parameter from the sub-report but I cannot link to the same paramter in the main report. I can only link to a returned field in the main report. SubmissionControlId is a parameter but it is not returned in the data.

Comment: Got this working. Change sub-report links was right so I am marking this as the answer.